# Dropdown box close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DIV that expands on click, it currently closes when another DIV is clicked but I would also like it to close on click, my code is below:

The Jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('.opReview').click(function(){
    $('.review').addClass('hide');
    $(this).children('.review').toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

The HTML Markup (Wordpress code can be ignored)

```
<article class="sixteen columns opReview">          

 <img class="opLogo" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/core/operator/90x58_operatorlogo/<?php echo $op_logo?>.png" alt="<?php echo($op_title)?>" >

  <div class="list_details">
    <div class="reviewTitle"><p>Click To </br> Read a review</p> </div>
  </div>

  <button class="claimBtn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-rotate-90"></i></button> 
        <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="review hide">
          <h1><?php echo $op_name; ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo $operator_review; ?></p>
        </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code hides all .review elements and then toggles the active one, unhiding it

```
$('.review').addClass('hide');
$(this).children('.review').toggleClass('hide');
```

you need to do exclude the current item from the first selector

```
$(this).siblings('.review').addClass('hide');
$(this).children('.review').toggleClass('hide');
```